# canonical charm openStack deployment , With AWS

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

Canonical charm openstack deployment with AWS for testing this deployment working perporly or not.
the component:  os ubuntu 20.04 LTS,
Openstack version :ussari,
maas 2.9 ,
juju 2.8.8 .
1.with this what prerequisite needed like no of node, network type and storage needed?
2.using AWS we need to set up maas or with out installing and configuring maas can we deploy the juju and openstack , is the deployment is possible without maas ?

Comment: Sorry this question is unreadable. It does look like 3 different questions. You need to limit yourself to one question per question. Also do not use all these short forms type the words out.